# SQL CLR UDT - how to define methods so the type needn't be dropped/re-added

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr, sqlclr

I'm playing around with writing CLR user-defined types in MS SQL Server. I've run into the following scenario:

1. Create new UDT
2. Deploy it to a database
3. Create a table with the UDT as one of the columns
4. Add a new method to the UDT
5. Try to deploy it again, but fail because SQL can't drop the UDT

Is there some way to define the methods on the UDT in such a way as to not have to drop and add the type? I feel like as long as I'm not changing the underlying storage, it should be fine. But I don't know the particulars of it.

Comment: I think , if UDT has any sql dependecy like Sproc than it will not allow you to drop. You need to drop all dependencty first.